# using variable within quotation marks

Tags: scripts, awk

```
awk -v input="$constrained" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(toupper(input), user)
        fmt = "%-4s %-8s     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.050\n"
    }
    {print}
    /<< matched line >>/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf fmt, user[i], user[i]"_GPS"
        exit
    }
' ./text_data > text_data_2
```

In the above codes, I want to define variable for `0.050 0.050  0.050`. I tried using with

```
echo -n "##### numeric value?  ####?"
read value
fmt = "%-4s %-8s     NNN    $value $value  $value\n"
```

but within the quotation marks, `$value` variable cannot be defined. How can I define this variable inside the quotation marks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pass the variable using `-v` the same as you do for your `input` variable

```
awk -v input="$constrained" -v value="0.05"
```

then use `sprintf` within your `BEGIN` block to construct the format string e.g.

```
BEGIN {
  n = split(toupper(input), user);
  fmt = sprintf("%%-4s %%-8s     NNN    %-4.3f %-4.3f %-4.3f\n", value, value, value, value);
}
```

Note the use of `%%` to produce literal `%` in the `fmt` string.

---

To test that it's constructing the correct format string, we can add print statements, first for the `fmt` string itself and then for the resulting print statement:

```
$ awk -v value="0.05" '
    BEGIN{
      fmt = sprintf("%%-4s %%-8s     NNN    %-4.3f %-4.3f %-4.3f\n", value, value, value, value);
      print fmt;
      printf(fmt, "test", "testval");
    }'
%-4s %-8s     NNN    0.050 0.050 0.050

test testval      NNN    0.050 0.050 0.050
```

Comment: awk -v input="$constrained" ' -v value="0.5" BEGIN { n = split(toupper(input)‌​, user) fmt = sprintf("\"%%-4s %%-8s NNN %-4f %-4f %-4f\\n\"", value, value, value); %it doesn't work. text_data file was created empty after executing the codes.

Comment: @deepblue_86 I think I was overzealous with the escaping - please see revised version